# Onedrive: How can I save a shared folder to my drive?

Tags: android, onedrive

I received an URL of a shared onedrive folder, I want to save that folder to my one drive account. But I can't see how this can be done. Can anyone give me any idea how this can be done?

Other cloud storage services like Dropbox has a simple button to add such shared folder to my Dropbox account. So I believe that can be done in one drive too.
The reason I need this is because I want to use those files from my one drive android app, if the shared folder can't be saved to my one drive account then I'll have to download and then reupload them to my account which is too much pain.

Answer (score 0):

Open the hamburger menu and open the "Shared" tab. Everything that was shared with your account should be there.

Comment: No it is not there. Because it was not explicitly shared with me, rather it is shared as a public folder via a URL. In the shared tab there are only the folders that were explicitly shared with me.

Comment: Then you'll have to perform the painful steps of downloading and re-uploading it.